# not able to install packages in pycharm on windows 10, getting SSL failed to verify error

Tags: ssl, certificate, pycharm

I am trying to install a HL7 apy package in pycharm using following steps.

`File-->Settings-->Project Interpreter-->click + sign-->search package-->Install package`. There after getting below error.

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/hl7apy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/hl7apy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping

Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/hl7apy/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/hl7apy/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/hl7apy/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/hl7apy/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/hl7apy/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hl7apy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for hl7apy
```

Anyone who can help.It's a bit urgent. I am able to install package through commmand terminal by adding trusted host. But when I import that package in pycharm IDE its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Create a pip config file at `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini`.

In my case, I had to create the pip folder and the pip.ini file then populated it with:

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
               pypi.org
               files.pythonhosted.org
```

Restarted PyCharm and it worked.

Refer to https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/?highlight=appdata#config-file and https://stackoverflow.com/a/29751768/1050178